# Problems displaying utf-8 characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

My hosting is free so I cannot modify the ini file.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I added the above in order to display utf-8 characters.

However I am having an error, possibly because of the line before the previous which is

```
 include 'header.php';
```

Can anyone assist me on this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: also you can use meta tag

Comment: you also need to store text in UTF8 field/table/database... UTF-8 needs to be all the way along the chain.

Comment: Also you can put right after your database connection charset for example `mysqli_set_charset($con, "UTF8");`. But show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your html head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Also as [Bartdude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2187273/bartdude) mentioned, make sure the data you are fetching is written in UTF-8

You should also make sure that the file is written in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You probably have already started outputting to the client. Try putting the `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` Line above the include.
Also include the error message in the post when asking an question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the encoding in your database.

[image]

Please check if **your tables** is in utf-8 encoding too.

[image]